# How to delete the primary key from without using constraint name

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, primary-key

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int PRIMARY KEY,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int
);
```

How to remove the primary key as there is no constraint defined?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> "How to remove PK as there is no constraint defined?"

Actually it's every bit as simple as you might hope:

```
SQL> create table t23 (id number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> select constraint_name, constraint_type
  2  from user_constraints
  3  where table_name = 'T23'
  4  /

CONSTRAINT_NAME                C
------------------------------ -
SYS_C0034419                   P

SQL> alter table t23 drop primary key;

Table altered.

SQL> select constraint_name, constraint_type
  2  from user_constraints
  3  where table_name = 'T23'
  4  /

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

run this to get constraint name :

```
SELECT *
  FROM user_cons_columns
 WHERE table_name = Persons;
```

then run

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
DROP CONSTRAINT <pk constraint>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can do it in 1 SQL command,without knowing the constraint name, but you can know the constraint name as in this case it would be defined by system. Something which starts with `SYS....`.

Alternatively you can use a `PLSQL` block to achieve the same.

See the example below for your case.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
ID int PRIMARY KEY,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Age int
);
```

Find constraint name

```
select CONSTRAINT_NAME 
 From  USER_CONSTRAINTS
 where table_name='PERSONS'
 AND  CONSTRAINT_TYPE='P';
```

`OUTPUT:= SYS_C0012152`

Drop Constraint

```
 ALTER TABLE PERSONS
 DROP CONSTRAINT SYS_C0012152;
```

Note: The constraint name `SYS_C0012152` is not enclosed in single quotes.

**PLSQL Block to do the same**

```
 declare 
 sql_stmt varchar2(255);
 cons_name varchar2(30);
 begin
   select CONSTRAINT_NAME 
   into cons_name
   From  USER_CONSTRAINTS
   where table_name='PERSONS'
   AND  CONSTRAINT_TYPE='P'; 

    sql_stmt:=' ALTER TABLE PERSONS
   DROP CONSTRAINT '||cons_name;

   dbms_output.put_line(sql_stmt);
   execute immediate sql_stmt;

 end;
```

Comment: Actually it can be done in one statement. See my answer.